# Uploadify FOLDER

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, upload, uploadify

I am using Uploadify to upload Files and using Codeigniter framework.

Here is my Uploadify code :

```
$("#change_profile_icon").uploadify({

                    'uploader'       : '/project/style/scripts/crop/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                    'script'         : 'http://localhost/project/pages/profile_icon',
                    'cancelImg'      : '/project/style/scripts/crop/uploadify/cancel.png',
                    'buttonText'     :'Upload image',
                    'width'          : '110',
                    'height'         : '30',
                    'queueID'        : 'fileQueue',
                    'auto'           : true,
                    'scriptData'     :{username :"<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username');?>",folder:"honda"},
                    'queueSizeLimit' : 1,
                    'multi'          : false,
                    'fileDesc'       : 'jpg',
                    'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.png',
                    'sizeLimit'      : '819200',//max size bytes - 800kb
                    'onComplete'     : function(event,queueID,fileObj,response,data) {
                                            alert("Completed");
                                            var dataresponse = eval('(' + response + ')');
                                            //$('#uploadifyUploader').remove();
                                        var filenametmp = "http://localhost"+(dataresponse.file).substring(0,(dataresponse.file).lastIndexOf("?"));
                                        var current_page = $('#page-list').val();

                                        },

                                        'onSelect' : function (){
                                        var folder =  $('#page-list option:selected').text(); //returns HONDA which is correct
$('#change_profile_icon').uploadifySettings('folder',folder);
}   ,           
                    'onError'        : function(){
                                            alert('error');
                                       }
                });
```

Here is my PHP part [script value in Uploadify]

```
function profile_icon()
    {
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // $fileTypes  = str_replace('*.','',$_REQUEST['fileext']);
    // $fileTypes  = str_replace(';','|',$fileTypes);
    // $typesArray = split('\|',$fileTypes);
    // $fileParts  = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    // if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$typesArray)) {
        // Uncomment the following line if you want to make the directory if it doesn't exist
        $targetPath = 'uploads/' .$_REQUEST['folder']. '/';
        $targetFile = $targetPath.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
        if (!file_exists($targetPath))
        {
         mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);
        }
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
    // } else {
    //  echo 'Invalid file type.';
    // }
}
```

Problem :

```
$targetPath = 'uploads/' .$_REQUEST['folder']. '/';
            $targetFile = $targetPath.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
            if (!file_exists($targetPath))
            {
             mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);
            }
```

Check the above codes taken from the PHP part.I think that `$_REQUEST['folder']` will give the folder name which is specified on the Uploadify script.The value of `folder` is `Honda`
But this gives something different.

I uploaded a file and this script uploaded it to

```
C:\wamp\www\project\uploads\project\home\editpage\honda\honda
```

On wamp server [I am in Localhost]

But how it comes ?? it should be

```
 C:\wamp\www\project\uploads\honda
```

Check the below...

```
  $targetPath = 'uploads/' .$_REQUEST['folder']. '/';
  $targetFile = $targetPath.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
```

The `targetPath` should be now `uploads/honda/`
and `targetFile` should be now `uploads/honda/fileName.ext`

I dont know what i am doing wrong and where it is....

Please help me.

Thank you .

**EDIT** : THE URL STRUCTURE OF CURRENT PAGE : `http://localhost/Project/home/editpage/honda/`
Where `home` is a controller and `editpage` is a function and `honda` is a argument.[Codeigniter framework]

---

```
SOLVED
```

I solved the issue,it is a bug in uploadify : The uploadify folder variable is not straight forward ,so that we should add a `slash` before that.

so it would be `var folder = "/"+ "FolderName";`
The problem is u cant return the data on server if u use just Folder name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue,it is a bug in uploadify : The uploadify folder variable is not straight forward ,so that we should add a slash before that.

so it would be var folder = "/"+ "FolderName"; The problem is u cant return the data on server if u use just Folder name.

Answer (score 0):

I will think you will get a lot of help to put your output into a file, :)

```
$myFile = "[full-folder-path]testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'] ." | ". print_r( $_REQUEST, true ) ."\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

But i think if you changes your line $targetPath to this

```
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
```

Remeber your folder need read/wirte rulls, its the only thing i can see its worng from your basic script to my script.

Comment: Could you please clarify your first block ? `move_uploaded_file` helping me alot.....

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the `folder` where you want to upload in the settings as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/uploads',
    'auto'      : true
  });
});
</script>
```

As in the above settings you missed out the `folder` option.

Comment: `onSelect' : function (){
                                        var folder =  $('#page-list option:selected').text(); //returns HONDA which is correct
$('#change_profile_icon').uploadifySettings('folder',folder);
}  `

Comment: OnSelect event is when you try to select the images from local folder but when you try to upload to server its different.

Comment: Yes you're right but where have you mentioned the folder name to upload?

Comment: You're just mentioning it but where did you provide it as "Honda" that you need to specify it as  'folder'    : '/Honda',

Comment: I solved it,it is a bug.What is the actual need to put `\ ` before folder ?? we are processing the folder on the backend script..so uploadify is responsible to send this information in a straight way :If there is no Slash it sends `Buggy`  information to the server,if its not possible they can throw some errors..

Comment: Kiran i am doing it on onSelect event.... and /Honda is not the actual upload folder...it is defined on server side..

Comment: You cannot do it in the Onselect event.

Comment: Kiran : i can do it on the `onSelect` event,and realize that the folder is just a variable and not the actual path.The Goal of uploadify with the `folder` is just to give user an option to set folder path,but due to security problems it is not a good idea to use it like the uploadify documentation says...