# Unkown error in uploadify

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

i am trying to implement uploadify and following are my settings

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="uploadify/uploadify.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="uploadify/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>

$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'   : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'     : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'folder'     : 'upload',
    'multi'      : true, 
});
```

I have uploaded the folder `uploadify` at the server , but still the uploadify was not be able to find the path properly and was giving me "Not Found uploadify.swf" error

so i have to hard code the following lines in `jquery.uploadify.js`

```
swf      : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
uploader : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
cancelImage     : 'uploadify/uploadify-cancel.png',
checkExisting   : 'uploadify/uploadify-check-existing.php',
```

after doing that "Not Found uploadify.swf" had gone , but when the the "SELECT FILES" button loads or the whole page gets load

**i am getting some strange error** don't know from where this request is being fired

```
GET http://www.example.com/client/plus/false 404 (Not Found)
```

I really dont under stand why its giving me this error

Comment: its able to find the swf , but i have a problem with GET http://www.example.com/client/plus/false 404 (Not Found) error

Comment: Are you doing it in php? if then sorry  don't know a bit of php but the sample I have done in .net with VB and t's working.Just gimme some time so that I can post the code for it f you need it.

Comment: This might be useful where I have provided solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399642/uploadify-folder/8399801#8399801

Comment: when i try /uplodify/uplodify.swf then it looks in to www.example.com/uploadify/uploadify.swf while i want to make it search in www.example.com/client/plus/uploadify/uploadify.swf so i am using uplodify/uploadify.swf

Comment: I tried everything , dont know whts missing :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug with Uploadify itself, [see this discussion](http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/7329/uploadify-v3-bug-unecessary-request-when-there-is-no-button_image_url-set-/p1). The SWF makes a request to the page for some reason.

Comment: tanya's solution http://goo.gl/CXOJIC or eugen_torica's one http://goo.gl/Xz8VH5 work. Uploadify 3.2.1.