# How to upload folders from uploadify?

Tags: javascript, php, uploadify

i am new to php and i am in learning phase. i am using uploadify to upload files and it is working fine. But now what i want is that when user selects specific file then all files and folders placed in the directory will be uploaded to server. I am unable to find any method of this but what i found is that user selects specific folders and then files.

[Uploadify FOLDER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399642/uploadify-folder)

i didnt find any method of uploading folders to server.

Comment: If you mean you select a folder and upload the contents, I'm not sure that Uploadify is made to do that.

Comment: no what i mean is can i differentiate from folders or files? if i can then i can zip folders and upload it on server and then i can unzip that.

Comment: You could check the mime-type and file extension of the uploaded file, check if it's in zip format and then extract it?

Comment: if it doesnt have any extension then i will zip it and upload it on server and then unzip it

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to zip a folder on your local filesystem using JavaScript. It would be a security issue for websites to be able to modify your files like that. You'd have to compress them manually and then upload the zip files.

Comment: i also wannna know whats the success function of uploadify script

Comment: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadsuccess/